# Java Swing. PaintingComponent

Tags: java, swing

Could you tell me, how can I pass variables (in this case - **a**) to the paintComponent? I think that way is wrong:

```
class PaintingComponent extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g, int a)
    {       
        raster.setPixel( 12, a, clr ); 
    }//paintComponent(Graphics g)
}
```

Comment: The "state" should either be part if component or be accessible by the component. You could set up your own class which can take additional parameters and the call it/them from your paintComponent method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. Thats how class hierarchies work, if you want to override a method, it has to have the same signature. The only thing you could do is get `a` from a method call.

Comment: Also, to make sure your signatures are unchanged use the @Override annotation; incidentally this will also highlight your problem.

Comment: @Gilead , So the JDK will sent an error when one uses `@Override` over `paintComponent()`?

Comment: @Guy the compiler wont accept your code if you mark a method with `@Override` but that method doesnt actually override/implement a method from one of the superclasses.